# Get text from hidden elements using Selenium WebDriver vba

Tags: html, vba, selenium

I'm trying to parse values from https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=3 to my Excel and so i used VBA. But when i try parse data from hidden elements such as [image]

I'm doing a cycle for where i run all games and only search games that each team play more then 5 times.
But my code works really well when i'm not enter this hidden elements.
Can someone help me how to enter my if else in elements that have hidden elements or not ?

```
For i = 1 To .FindElementsByXPath("//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2]").Count Step 2
           
           
           If IsNumeric(.FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i & "]").Text) And IsNumeric(.FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i & "]").Text) Then
               
               If CInt(.FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i & "]").Text) > 5 And CInt(.FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i & "]").Text) > 5 Then
                  
                  league = .FindElementByXPath("((((//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i & "]/../td//preceding::tr[@class='parent'])[last()])/td/font)[1]").Text

                   
                  If Not IsError(Application.Match(league, Worksheets("Ligas").Range("E:E"), 0)) Then
                      'Buscar dados se o numero de jogos for numérico
                      'Encontrar nome da liga
                      
                      hometeam = .FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i & "]/../td[1]").Text
                      awayteam = .FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i + 1 & "]/../td[1]").Text
                   
                      homegames = .FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i & "]").Text
                      awaygames = .FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i + 1 & "]").Text
                      
                      homegoalsscored = .FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i & "]/following-sibling::td[@class='sgreen'][2]").Text
                      awaygoalsscored = .FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i + 1 & "]/following-sibling::td[@class='sgreen'][2]").Text
                                      
                      homegoalsconceded = .FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgreen'][2])[" & i & "]/following-sibling::td[@class='sred'][1]").Text
                      awaygoalsconceded = .FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgreen'][2])[" & i + 1 & "]/following-sibling::td[@class='sred'][1]").Text
                      
                      gametime = .FindElementByXPath("(//*[@class='steam']/../td[@class='sgray'][2])[" & i & "]/../td[@valign='middle']/font").Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you test the .Attribute("style"), of a given node, return value you can determine if display:none ;

E.g. pseudo code

```
If <node>.Attribute("style") = "display:none ;" Then
    ' do something....
Else
   'do something different
End If
```

You can also test for substrings with Instr

```
If Instr(<node>.Attribute("style"), "display:none")  > 0 Then
    ' do something....
Else
   'do something different
End If
```

`<node>` is a placeholder for your node/element in the current iteration at whatever level the test needs to be; not clear from your question.

Comment: I want parse text of elements that have display:none or don't have. doing this if how i will get the value of the element ?

Comment: I'm only getting text value of elements that don't have hidden data

Comment: Can you https://pastebin.com/ full code? You are expecting the text from hidden items as well?

Comment: code is working if elements not hidden, but i want parse data from hidden and not hidden games for leagues that was selected in excel